# Running local MySQL instance + connecting to Crystal Reports

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports-2016

I am on Windows 7 32-bit.

I have a .SQL file database backup/dump from our relational database software/server. I need to run this locally, as our relational database is going to the cloud where ODBC connections, etc won't be permitted at first. I use this MySQL database for reporting and so I still need to connect it to Crystal Reports, but locally. I have a daily .SQL backup file I can download from an FTP site to keep it up to date.
I am attempting a local MySQL database instance now, no server just a local database that I can query from in Crystal Reports. But I am having issues.

How do I:

```
1. Successfully Run a local instance of MySQL on my computer.
2. Connect the instance to Crystal Reports via MySQL driver setup.
3. Perform a import + restore to bring the database copy into the live instance.
```

download MySQL installer here:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

And then I downloaded MySql WorkBench.

At workbench's connection configuration I put hostname as "127.0.0.1" ( I also attempted "localhost"), port "3306", user: "root", password is empty.

I click "test connection" and it gives me this error:

"Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)"
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your posted instructions that you followed, I didn't see any mention of mysql itself being installed.

The MySQL workbench is not the actual server, but a suite of tools use to help manage it.

In the installer for MySQL you should see an option for an instance of mysql or some verbiage to that effect, if not "MySQL Server". That is what you also need to install.

Comment: I have the server installed now, but Work Bench won't install now. This installer is driving me bonkers. how do I download both the Server and the Workbench, the two are never on the DL list at the same time? I am doing the "full" installation and when that isnt working I did the "developer" one.